# Filter out the last available day of a quarter in the dataframe in which Quarter column is already present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I want to get the row for the last available date in a Quarter in a pandas df. There's already a column denoting the Quarter of that particular year.

```
 player   amount  date       Quarter
 dan       10    2021-06-29  2Q21
 dmitri    45    2021-06-30  2Q21
 darren    15    2021-12-31  4Q21
 xae12     40    2021-12-30  4Q21
 except    89    2022-01-31  1Q22
```

For the above df. I should get the following rows as output (the ones with latest date in a particular Quarter)

```
 player   amount  date       Quarter
 dmitri    45    2021-06-30  2Q21
 darren    15    2021-12-31  4Q21
```

**Note**: The last row shouldn't appear in the result as it is not the actual end date of a Quarter (e.g. June 30, Dec 31 etc.)

Any help is appreciated. Right now I am trying to use pandasql library but I don't want to inject SQL type queries for pandas manipulations in my code. I would prefer it doing in a more pandas native way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.offsets.QuarterEnd`:

```
# df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) 
print (df.loc[df["date"] == (df["date"]+pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0))])

   player  amount       date Quarter
1  dmitri      45 2021-06-30    2Q21
2  darren      15 2021-12-31    4Q21
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the latest dates like so:

```
lst = list()
for quarter in df.Quarter.unique():
   lst.append(df.loc[df['Quarter'] == quarter].date.max())
```

This way you get the latest for each quarter and you can later filter out dates who are not the end of the quarter and finally get the requested result like so:

```
df.loc[df['date'].isin(lst)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It works, but I have a query. how should I filter the dates which are not the end of a Quarter (here quarter end should be a business date).

Comment: From a quick google search I see that Q1 ends at 31st of March, Q2 ends at June 30th, Q3 ends at September 30th and Q4 ends at 31st of December. Now that i think about it, Since all End-of-Quarter dates are prep-known, you can create a list ahead of time containing the dates you want. As regards to how, you can use the "datetime" builtin package or write your dates as strings or however you like.
If this answer helps you, please consider up-voting and accepting this answer.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about quarter end date which is a business date. Thanks. I will look into it

Comment: On searching, can be done with BQuarterEnd() from pandas.tseries.offsets

Answer (score 1):

You can use the datetime functions of pandas to calculated the expected end of quarter:

```
# calculate theoretical Quarter end
df['end_quarter'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
                       .dt.to_period("Q")
                       .dt.end_time.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    )
# filter
(df.groupby('Quarter', as_index=False)
   .last()
   .query('date == end_quarter')
   .drop('end_quarter', axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
  Quarter  player  amount        date
1    2Q21  dmitri      45  2021-06-30
```

Note that one of your expected lines was not an end of quarter (December 30 is not, it should be December 31)